# Find COM interface of specific application

Tags: c#, com

I have a very specific application controlling a laboratory device. There is no documentation for this application. However, it might be possible that this application has a COM interop interface.

1. How do I determine if this specific application actually has a COM interop interface?
2. If it has COM interop, how do I get the required GUID or String for the CreateObject("x") method?
3. Alternatively, is it correct that there should (always?) be a COM related DLL that I can import into the Visual Studio Solution to find the COM interface of the application?

Comment: Search the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` for any registered interfaces.

Comment: Search for .tlb files or .tlb files embedded in .dlls files from what the product ships. You can use OleView tool from Windows SDK to open tlb in .tlb or .dll files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer Note a .tlb is not mandatory. However, if it's not publicly documented by the vendor, there are 99% chances there's no COM object available, developers don't provide COM objects just for fun of writing code, it's usually an extra layer (of code and work) above internal features